# Display Groupname with selected item on Dropdown using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

This is my Code

```js
var app = angular.module('myExample', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {
  
    $scope.myOptions = [{
            "id": 106,
            "group": "Employee",
            "label": "Id"
        },{
            "id": 107,
            "group": "Employee",
            "label": "Name"
        },{
            "id": 110,
            "group": "Department",
            "label": "Id"
        }];
    $scope.getSelectedField=function(){
        //$scope.myOption=$scope.myOption;
        alert($scope.myOption);
    }; 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select
        ng-model="myOption"
        ng-options="value.group+'.'+value.label as value.label group by value.group for value in myOptions" ng-change="getSelectedField()" >
            <option>--</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        selected value: {{myOption}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code selected Item display on dropdown , But I want to display Groupname with Selected Item on Dropdown.for example when user select id now display 'Employee.id' on Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Here `value.group+'.'+value.label` will display on dropdown. Before you were displaying only `value.label`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select
        ng-model="myOption"
        ng-options="value.group+'.'+value.label as value.group+'.'+value.label group by value.group for value in myOptions" ng-change="getSelectedField()" >
            <option>--</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        selected value: {{myOption}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Dropdown values like optgroup format only , but when user select item from dropdown i want to display groupname with item on dropdown.